# ImportError: No module named datetime

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-14.04

When I upgrade my Ubuntu into 14.04 from 12.04, this time I get this error:

```
 ImportError: No module named datetime
```

Comment: you get this error while doing what ?

Comment: Yes, while I'm upgrading it and also after it finish upgrading, the error is still there.

Comment: the version I'm using is python  2.7.6

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This happened to me when I created a virtualenv and then upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04.

I had to delete my virtualenv and recreate it, and after doing that, everything worked again.

Comment: I had the same problem after I did apt-get dist-upgrade my Debian. Solution was to delete the virtualenv and recreate it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Simply running `mkvirtualenv $my_venv_name` solved it for me.

Comment: same happened for me after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04

Answer (score 40):

Just run this command. It worked like a charm!

```
$ cp /usr/bin/python2.7 $(which python2.7)
```

This just happened to me after the 14.10 update, and it seems to be because my virtual environments have old copies of `/usr/bin/python2.7` that — unlike the new binary — do not include `datetime` built-in, and so get an error when they cannot find it on disk anywhere. The new interpreter seems to import it without any file I/O (try running it under strace to check).

[More info here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509283/python-no-module-named-datetime)

Comment: I took this a step further, "rm venv/bin/python*", then reinitialize with "virtualenv venv". Less destructive compared to rebuilding the whole venv.

Comment: **You deserve a coffee! Thanks :)** - Also caused by upgrading underlying `Ubuntu 14.04` to `Ubuntu 16.04.1` without touching the virtual environment.

Answer (score 10):

I tried to re-install it by these steps.

```
1. remove the old version of venv
2. virtualenv venv
3. .venv/activate/bin
4. pip install -r requirements/ requirements.txt
```

And it works perfectly. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 10):

just reinitialize the virtualenv by:

```
cd <virtualenv-dir>
virtualenv .
```

Comment: This worked for me with one change. 'virtualenv .' gave me the error: 'IOError: [Errno 40] Too many levels of symbolic links' so I did: 'rm bin/python*' and then 'virtualenv .' succeeded.

Answer (score 8):

If by chance you come across this error while trying to renew your LetsEncrypt certificate (like I did) I found the solution here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/850669/668101

Remove this folder and rerun LetsEncrypt and it will recreate all the relevant files and avoid the error from this thread.

```
rm ~/.local/share/letsencrypt -R
```

Comment: Good tip! Thanks for the info!! The only thing is that the term "thread" doesn't really apply to StackOverflow as this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site :) Otherwise, this was really helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you use `virtualenv`, updating it might solve this issue

```
virtualenv /path/to/old/virtualenv/
```

Answer (score 3):

Try...

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
[... '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',...]
```

if lib-dynload not included in sys.path, You could not `import datetime`

check it!

Comment: had to create the lib-dynload directory and copy paste contents of Python-2.7.*/build/lib.linux-***-2.7 into it

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me on upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04 to 15.10.

I solved it by upgrading pip and then removing and recreating the virtual env:

```
$ easy_install --upgrade pip
$ rmvirtualenv <my_virtual_env>
$ mkvirtualenv <my_virtual_env>
```

(I use virtualenvwrapper)

Answer (score 1):

1. clear virtual env, consider VIRTUAL is the name of the virtual environment

   virtualenv --clear VIRTUAL
2. Now activate it and install from requirements.txt

   source VIRTUAL/bin/activate
   pip install -r requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

If you face datetime import issue using IntelliJ PyCharm or Idea and from Console/Terminal it works fine, you should just duplicate/recreate running configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this error with LetsEncrypt trying to renew and in order to fix I had to go back to the letsencrypt site and reinstall certbot because they have changed how it works on Ubuntu.

https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-nginx

Here are the commands I ended up running, your commands may be different.

#### snap was not installed in my Ubuntu instance

```
sudo apt install snapd 
sudo snap install core; sudo snap refresh core
```

#### remove the old certbot

```
sudo apt-get remove certbot
sudo snap install --classic certbot
```

#### make the "certbot" command work with old config

```
sudo ln -s /snap/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbot
```

#### run a couple tests

```
sudo certbot --nginx
sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

#### Actually renew and restart server

```
sudo certbot renew
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart nginx
```

#### Update cronjob

Then I needed to update my cronjob so that it used `sudo certbot renew` instead of the full path to certbot that I was using before.

```
crontab -e
```

contents of crontab

```
42 3,15 * * * sudo certbot renew --quiet --no-self-upgrade
24 1,18 * * * sudo certbot renew --quiet --no-self-upgrade
5 4 * * 7 sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart nginx
```