# Specify which Python version interprets an executable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I developed an application with Python 3 that produces various executables. I then used `setuptools` to build and distribute this application, again all using Python 3.

When this application is installed in a test environment, the executables are being correctly deployed to the `bin` folder and thus become invokable from anywhere in the system. However, when these executables are invoked, the system tries to use the Python 2 interpreter, leading to an exception. How can I make sure the Python interpreter is used when I invoke these executables?

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: I am developing on Ubuntu 16.04 and testing on other Debian based distributions.

Comment: How did you install it? If you run `python3 setup.py install` then the generated start script is genrated with a python3 shebang. If you used python(2) to install it, then also the script will be started using that interpreter.

Comment: I did run `python3 setup.py install`. How can check the resulting start script?

Comment: It's a script, just open it in a text editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made sure `install` was run with Python 3 and that the resulting script included the correct header. Still I kept getting exceptions from Python 2.7.

Out of desperation I created a new Python 3 virtual environment and in it the scripts started working properly. There are previous reports of old virtual environments going haywire, particularly [during a system upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26499478/2066215).

For future reference, the command I used:

`mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.5 venv_p3`

Answer (score -2):

You might need to use bash [shebangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165808/should-i-use-a-shebang-with-bash-scripts) on your scripts, which are small strings at the beginning that specifies what binary should interpret them.

In your case you need to add `#!/usr/bin/env python3` at the beginning of your scripts. The bash shell should read this and pass the script to your `python3` installled interpreter.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# This should work on python3 and fail on python2:
print("Hello from python3!")
```

Comment: The scripts placed in bin are usually generated from the defined entry points in `setup.py` by setuptools, the shebang is autogeneratet pointing to the interpreter used during installation. And a "bash shebang" is `#!/bin/bash`, it should be only "shebang" in this context, and it's not bash (or other shell) interpreting that line but the os.